# Using Acceptance-Rejection Algorithm to Target an Exponential Distribution

Tags: bayesian, sampling

I'm wondering if I could use the Acceptance-Rejection Algorithm to sample from the Exponential distribution, or from some random variable $X$ dist on $(\lambda)$, such that $f(x; \lambda)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$.

Choosing the "easy" function to sample from, $g(x): g(x) = e^x$, I'm now faced finding $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$h(x) = \frac{f(x)}{cg(x)}$$ has been maximized.

However, $h(x) = c^{-1} \lambda e^{x(1-\lambda)}$ does not have a maximum; solving for $h'(x) = 0$ doesn't yield any solution.

Textbooks and notes I've seen suggest that we want $c$ to be as close to $1$ as possible. In this case, why couldn't I just say $c=1$?

If I can't find a $c$, should I be using another method altogether, i.e. inverse function?

Comment: Why is $g(x)=e^{x}$ easy to sample from - It doesn't normalise?

Comment: @Nadiels I could be missing something, of course, but I thought it was easy since using an inverse trasnform from a uniform sample $U$, we have $X = \ln U$

Comment: Since $U \in [0, 1]$ then $\ln U$ has support $(-\infty, 0)$, that is you are generating the 'usual' standard exponential random variable scaled by $-1$. Obviously with one variable supported on the negative numbers and your target distribution supported on the positive this would be a bad proposal indeed!

Comment: but there is another slight more subtle point, you need a scale multipled of your proposal distribution to bound the target density everywhere - and two different exponential density functions for different values of $\lambda$ intersect

Comment: @Nadiels Your first point didn't occur to me- but your second one did and I tried playing with different values for $\lambda$. I think I'm just going to stick with the inverse transform method, unless anyone has other insight to give. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah the inverse transform method is definitely the 'best' choice for sampling exponential random variables, but if you wanted to try AR just to see how it works the Cauchy distribution or something like it might work, obviously always rejecting for negative values, or a folded Cauchy I guess